# At around or at round

Tags: prepositions, british-english, time

What preposition do we use in **British English** when we talk about time?

> I came at **around** five o'clock.
>
> I came at **round** five o'clock.

Can I use the preposition **above**?

> I came at **about** five o'clock.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use numerous prepositions/modifiers (around, about, nearly, almost, just on) but NOT *round*.

Comment: You can say "I came round at five o'clock" but the meaning is different, and it doesn't imply that "five o'clock" was the *approximate* time. when I came.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be:

> I came around five o'clock

or

> I came at about five o'clock

This is [according to the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/approximations-around-four-o-clock), so proper BrE.
With the word "round" it won't work, that [means only movement](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/around-or-round) (or shape), not approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Korvin's answer, the reason many people may think it is "round" is because the "a" does not seem to be pronounced when you actually say the sentence.